# C++ problems when lnker finalizes compilation process on overloaded operator

Tags: c++, namespaces, operator-overloading, linker-errors

Consider having the following header file (c++): `myclass.hpp`

```
#ifndef MYCLASSHPP_
#define MYCLASSHPP_

namespace A {
namespace B {
namespace C {

class myclass { /* Something */ };

myclass& operator+(const myclass& mc, int i);

}}}

#endif
```

Consider the implemenation file: `myclass.cpp`

```
#include "myclass.hpp"
using namespace A::B::C;

myclass& operator+(const myclass& mc, int i) {
   /* Doing something */
}
```

Consider main file: `main.cpp`

```
#include "myclass.hpp"

int main() {
   A::B::C::myclass el = A::B::C::myclass();
   el + 1;
}
```

Well, the linker tells me that there is an undefined reference to `A::B::C::operator+(A::B::C::myclass const&, int)`

What's the problem here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just because you're `using namespace A::B::C` in the implementation file doesn't mean that everything declared in there is automatically in the `A::B::C` namespace (otherwise, all definitions would become ambiguous if you were `using` more than one namespace).

myclass.cpp should look something like:

```
namespace A {
namespace B {
namespace C {
    myclass operator+(const myclass& mc, int i) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Or (I find this cleaner):

```
using namespace A::B::C;

myclass A::B::C::operator+(const myclass& mc, int i) {
    // ...
}
```

Currently, the compiler thinks you've declared one `operator+` function in the `A::B::C` namespace, and defined a *different* function that's not in a namespace at all, leading to your link error.

Comment: I see, thanks... In 2 mins checking this...

Answer (score 5):

A `using namespace` directive changes the name search order.  It doesn't change where definitions are placed.

You defined `operator+` in the wrong namespace.

Answer (score 1):

the "using" keyword is only useful to resolve the called method. It cannot be used when defining the method. Your statement actually just defines the method in global namespace.
Your definition should have been:

```
A::B::C::myclass A::B::C::operator+(const myclass& mc, int i) {
   /* Doing something */
}
```

when you are calling the method, both the following do the same thing:

```
using namespace A::B::C;
myclass tmp;
tmp + 1;
```

-OR-

```
A::B::C::myclass tmp;
tmp + 1;
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Yeah, actually this is also what I ended up doing... could not understand for sure if it was a namespace problem, but now it is clear! Thankyou guys